# How can i move my methods out of my main code file

Tags: c#, class, methods

I'm having a program that is generating some stats from the web but now i ended up having 30+ methods in my main file and i want to split my methods to other files so i can maintain them better and the main program will much readable. (Im new to c# and i dont know how i can do this i need some reference)

My Methods are like these.

1)String Methods

```
cut_string(string text)

find_string(string text)
```

2)Web Methods

```
get_url_source(string url)
```

3)Specific Web Methods 1

...

4)Specific Web Methods 2

...

Now my main program is searching in a range of pages and generating some data.
Example `myweb.com/1-100/`

```
using imports...

namespace PirateBot
{
    public partial class MyProgram : Form
    {
        private void My_Button(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            start_program();
        }

        private void start_program()
        {
            for (int i = 1 ; i =<100 ; i++)
            {
                //use web methods
                //use string methods
                //etc
            }
        }
        //my methods...
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok, and what is the problem?

Comment: I dont know how to do it or if i should use instance's i need some reference.

Comment: Seems like you need to learn Object Oriented Programing. Maybe some of the answers here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1784824/best-c-sharp-tutorials-for-a-newbie can help

Comment: Do you have 30 methods belonging to the same class? If the class is `partial` (and it looks so), you can still have the class split over many files, but normally one uses `partial` because different "parts" of the class a written/generated in different ways (some parts might be generated by different kind of generators, and one part can be hand-written). You could also consider if there's a better design than having that many methods in one type, but it might be OK to have it like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You require [Extract Class](http://sourcemaking.com/refactoring/extract-class) refactoring.

Group similar/related methods together and move to different class.

Example  (Following can be your new classes)

```
class StringHelper
{
  // String specific methods
}  

class WebHelper
{
  // String specific methods
}  

...
```

Comment: It seems that is what im looking for, gonna read it and reply back.

Comment: but make meaningful class names. ___Helper does not sounds good. Looks more like utility class.

Comment: Yes the class name is the least of my worries, the link that you forward me too was exactly what i was looking for, thanks for the fast reply.